# C# Passing Values from Form 1 to Form 2

Tags: c#, forms

I am doing my school subject project and I can´t pass the number that is inside the text box from form 1 to form 2´s text box, I know that are very examples in the internet but it is not working please guys can you help me doing this in other way:

Form 1 code:

```
public partial class fmnumbergamer : Form
{

    public fmnumbergamer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void fmnumbergamer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnplay.Visible = false;

        txtinformacao.Visible = false;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Visible = true;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Enabled = false;

        txtinformacaonumeros.Text = ("Marque nas Caixas de texto os numeros  e as estrelas com o qual pretende jogar e carregue nos botões Assinalar");

        txtinformacao.Text = ("Após ter carregado nos botões assinalar carregue no botãp PLAY para ir para o sorteio do PSI - Euromilhões");
    }

    private void txtnumero1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar <'0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void txtnumero2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtnumero3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtnumero4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtnumero5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtestrela1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtestrela2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void btnassinalarnumeros_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtnumero1.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero2.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero3.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero4.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero5.Enabled = false;
        btnassinalarnumeros.Enabled = false;
        txtinformacao.Visible = true;
        btnplay.Visible = true;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Visible = false;
        txtinformacao.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void btnassinalarestrelas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtestrela1.Enabled = false;
        txtestrela2.Enabled = false;
        btnassinalarestrelas.Enabled = false;
        txtinformacao.Visible = true;
        btnplay.Visible = true;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Visible = false;
        txtinformacao.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void GBPchave_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
```

and here the code from Form 2:

```
public partial class fmpsieuromilhoes : Form
{

    public fmpsieuromilhoes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void fmpsieuromilhoes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtvalorjackpot.Enabled = false;
        txtvalorjackpot.Text = "15.000.000,00€";
        btnIntrouzirNovaChave.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnLimparCampos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtuserfifhtnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfirstnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfirststarnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfourthnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfsecondstarnumber.Text = "";
        txtusersecondnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserthirdnumber.Text = "";
        btnIntrouzirNovaChave.Visible = true;
    }
    private void btnIntrouzirNovaChave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        using (fmnumbergamer NB = new fmnumbergamer())
            NB.ShowDialog();
        Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which text box values do u want to pass from `fmpsieuromilhoes` (Form1) form to `fmnumbergamer` (Form2) form?

Comment: I want to pass from form1 the value in txtnumero1 (that contains the value(from 1 and 50(only one number))) to the text box in form 2 - txtuserfirstnumber.

Comment: @Dark Siege 99 i saw, you asking for 1 - 50 value, what you need, describe briefly

Comment: How can I explain, This is " a game" that the form 1 is to the user choose is own numbers between 1 and 50(but he can only put one in every text boxes) then he presses the button "Play", and form 1 "closes" and the value that the user wrote in the text box from the form 1 goes to the text box in the form 2.

Answer (score 1):

In the recepient form that's `fmnumbergamer` *add public property*:

```
public partial class fmnumbergamer: Form {
  ...

  //TODO: Change property name to more appropriate one
  public int LotteryValue {
    get {
      //TODO: Check if I've put the right text box here
      return int.Parse(txtinformacao.Text);
    }
    set {
      if ((value < 1) || (value > 50))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value"); 

      //TODO: Check if I've put the right text box here 
      txtinformacao.Text = value.ToString();
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

When *invoking* this form just **set** the property

```
private void btnIntrouzirNovaChave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Hide();
   using (fmnumbergamer NB = new fmnumbergamer()) {
     //TODO: Put right value here
     NB.LotteryValue = 34;

     NB.ShowDialog();
   }
   Show();
}
```

Comment: I want to pass a value between 1 and 50 like lottery, it is the same basic´s?  How it gets

Comment: Just change property's type and (slightly) get and set

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Create one constructor for class Form2 which takes string as argumant like this

```
 public Form2(string yourTxt)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  textbox2.Text=yourTxt;
}
```

And call form2 in form1 like this

```
  Form2 frm=new Form2(textbox1.text);
  frm.Show();
```

Comment: I want to pass a value between 1 and 50 like lottery, it is the same basic´s?  How it gets

Comment: Do u mean u want to pass random value? or if its int you can pass it using int.Parse

Comment: the user write a number between 1 and 50 only

Comment: have u tried any of the solution. you can pass n number of parameters

Comment: If you have "the Project" it will be more easy to explain

Comment: Cant u just post what u have tried and what output u r getting

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for fmnumbergamer form

```
private int _value;
public fmnumbergamer(int value){
  _value = value;
}
```

pass the value to constructor of fmnumbergamer form

```
using (fmnumbergamer NB = new fmnumbergamer(Convert.ToInt32(YourFirstTextbox.Text))
        NB.ShowDialog();
```

And set textBox with _value in fmnumbergamer form load

```
private void fmnumbergamer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do whatever you want with _value
}
```

Comment: I want to pass a value between 1 and 50 like lottery, it is the same basic´s?  How it gets

Comment: You mean you don't know exactly how many values you want to pass?

Comment: How can I explain, This is " a game" that the form 1 is to the user choose is own numbers between 1 and 50(but he can only put one in every text boxes) then he presses the button "Play", and form 1 "closes" and the value that the user wrote in the text box from the form 1 goes to the text box in the form 2.

Comment: Then replace every string I wrote with int. It is easy. do you want me to do it for you?

Comment: Is giving me a error it said that Application.Run(new fmnumbergamer()); doesnt take 0 arguments, but when I write the value: he said that value does not exists in the current context

Comment: Pass the parameter into constructor. Do you even know what does the parameter and constructor mean? Are you sure you don't need a programming course?

Comment: it is working now, sorry Azade I dont sleep any hours and this is what appends

Answer (score 0):

Replace ur form1 code with this code:

```
public partial class fmnumbergamer : Form
{

    public fmnumbergamer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public fmnumbergamer(fmpsieuromilhoes form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtnumero1.Text = form.txtuserfirstnumber.Text;
        txtnumero2.Text = form.txtusersecondnumber.Text;
        txtnumero3.Text = form.txtuserthirdnumber.Text;
        txtnumero4.Text = form.txtuserfourthnumber.Text;
        txtnumero5.Text = form.txtuserfifhtnumber.Text;
    }

    private void fmnumbergamer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnplay.Visible = false;

        txtinformacao.Visible = false;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Visible = true;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Enabled = false;

        txtinformacaonumeros.Text = ("Marque nas Caixas de texto os numeros  e as estrelas com o qual pretende jogar e carregue nos botões Assinalar");

        txtinformacao.Text = ("Após ter carregado nos botões assinalar carregue no botãp PLAY para ir para o sorteio do PSI - Euromilhões");
    }

    private void txtnumero1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void txtnumero2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtnumero3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtnumero4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtnumero5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtestrela1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void txtestrela2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void btnassinalarnumeros_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtnumero1.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero2.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero3.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero4.Enabled = false;
        txtnumero5.Enabled = false;
        btnassinalarnumeros.Enabled = false;
        txtinformacao.Visible = true;
        btnplay.Visible = true;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Visible = false;
        txtinformacao.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void btnassinalarestrelas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtestrela1.Enabled = false;
        txtestrela2.Enabled = false;
        btnassinalarestrelas.Enabled = false;
        txtinformacao.Visible = true;
        btnplay.Visible = true;
        txtinformacaonumeros.Visible = false;
        txtinformacao.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void GBPchave_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And Form2 code with this:

```
public partial class fmpsieuromilhoes : Form
{

    public fmpsieuromilhoes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void fmpsieuromilhoes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtvalorjackpot.Enabled = false;
        txtvalorjackpot.Text = "15.000.000,00€";
        btnIntrouzirNovaChave.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnLimparCampos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtuserfifhtnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfirstnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfirststarnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfourthnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserfsecondstarnumber.Text = "";
        txtusersecondnumber.Text = "";
        txtuserthirdnumber.Text = "";
        btnIntrouzirNovaChave.Visible = true;
    }
    private void btnIntrouzirNovaChave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        using (fmnumbergamer NB = new fmnumbergamer(this))
            NB.ShowDialog();
        Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to pass an int value only one number between 1 and 50(the number is the user that choose)

Comment: U was talking about TextBoxs, where are those no 1 and 50? In which textBox?

Comment: How can I explain, This is " a game" that the form 1 is to the user choose is own numbers between 1 and 50(but he can only put one in every text boxes) then he presses the button "Play", and form 1 "closes" and the value that the user wrote in the text box from the form 1 goes to the text box in the form 2.

Comment: no because I have 5 text boxes for 5 different numbers and 2 other text boxes for 2 stars(that are numbers to(but this ones are between 1 and 11)

Comment: Do u want to pass 2 other text boxes for 2 start number?

Comment: this is more easy to explain, I have 7 text boxes and I want to pass 1 value(int - 1 between 50)for each text box to the other 7 text boxes in form 2